# How does @@ work in input statement?

Tags: sas

I am trying to understand how does sas read this code.

```
         data scores;
    input Grade : $1. @@;
     check='abcdf';
   if verify(grade,check)>0 then 
  put @1 'INVALID ' grade=;
   datalines;
 a b c b c d f a a q a b d d b z
     ;
     run;
```

The log gives the following result:

```
    INVALID Grade=q
    INVALID Grade=z
```

Can anyone tell me how does SAS read the data and what does @@ stand for?Is each observation of the field - Grade read for each "grade= "?

Comment: What did you do to try and figure it out? Did you read the documentation?  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/68024/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0oaql83drile0n141pdacojq97s.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data scores;
    input Grade : $1.;
```

would only read the first character on each line. This is because, after each execution of an `input` statement, a new line from the file is read into the input buffer, even if there is a lot left on the current line.

With `Grade : $1. @@;`, you instruct SAS not to read another line, unless all data on the current line is processed.